# How to Restore entire farm without configuration database?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, backup, restore

I need help to restore my SharePoint farm.
Actually by mistake i deleted my configuration database and i don't have backup of it. but i have full farm back file "spbr0004". Is it possible to restore by using this file?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, full backup farm has 2 meanings:

1. You selected all components in your farm and then use **Full** backup type.
2. You didn't select all components in your farm and then use **Full** backup type.

Anyway, If you select configuration database (SharePoint_Config component by default), you can restore.

You can learn about process through this **[article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428311.aspx)**.